# android: increase width width of quotespan strip

Tags: android

i am using quoteSpan for a textView

```
SpannableString t1 = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(myItems.get(position).getTest()));
        t1.setSpan(new QuoteSpan(Color.RED), 0, t1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_PARAGRAPH);
        txtView1.setText(t1);
```

but it displays a very very thin line on the left of the text, is there any way to make this line thicker so that it looks better?

Comment: see this https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/style/QuoteSpan.java

Comment: thank you! :) sorry if i sound dumb but but how do i use this? do i have to copy this java file in my project or just use one of the methods or what :(

Comment: copy and increase two constans

Comment: did it but no change. plus the line return TextUtils.QUOTE_SPAN; gives and error {QUOTE_SPAN could nto be resloved}

Comment: let it only implement LeadingMarginSpan, remove ParcelableSpan methods

Comment: and what, did it work?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Quote Span class constructor that accepts a Parcel and use this Java code :

```
Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
parcel.writeInt(getColor(R.color.colorAccent));//stripe color
parcel.writeInt(10);//stripe width
parcel.writeInt(10);//gap width
parcel.setDataPosition(0);
QuoteSpan quoteSpan = new QuoteSpan(parcel);
SpannableString string = new  SpannableString(getString(R.string.top_review));
string.setSpan(quoteSpan, 0, string.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.quoteSpan)).setText(string);
parcel.recycle(); // put the parcel object back in the pool
```

If you want in Kotlin see this Repository :
[Custom Android Quote Span with AppCompat support](https://github.com/sourin00/Android-Quote-Span-with-AppCompat-)